# Dev C++ размер exe

Tags: c++, компиляция

Установил Dev C++. Скомпилировал простенькую программу. Размер с -s 691 kb, без 1,3 mb.

### Процесс компиляции: Processing C++ source file...

- C++ Compiler: %BinDir0%\g++.exe
- Command: g++.exe "C:\C++\shix.cpp" -o "C:\C++\shix.exe" -std=c++11 -I"%CppIncludeDir0%" -I"%CppIncludeDir1%" -I"%CppIncludeDir2%" -I"%CppIncludeDir2%\c++" -L"%LibDir0%" -L"%LibDir1%" -s

### Compilation results...

- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0
- Output Filename: C:\C++\shix.exe
- Output Size: 691 KiB
- Compilation Time: 2,17s

Вопрос, как уменьшить размер exe?

Comment: В общем случае - не включать отладочную информацию, компилировать с динамически линкуемыми библиотеками...

Comment: в mingw должна быть такая программка strip для обрезки отладочной информации
а для чего вам уменьшать? если не секрет, НГМД уж вроде больше не применяются :)

Comment: Попробуйте еще добавить флажки `-flto -Os`.

Comment: На Си та же программа 16 KiB. И работает везде. Чудеса...Страуструпа.

Answer (score 1):

Взял [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075) (окружение MINGW64), проверяю hello world.

| Компилятор | Флажки | Размер |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `clang++` (14) |  | 120 КБ |
| `clang++` (14) | `-s` | 16 КБ |
| `clang++` (14) | `-Os -s` | 16 КБ |
| `clang++` (14) | `-Os -s -flto -fuse-ld=lld` | 15 КБ |
| `g++` (12) |  | 122 КБ |
| `g++` (12) | `-s` | 18 КБ |
| `g++` (12) | `-Os -s` | 18 КБ |
| `g++` (12) | `-Os -s -flto` | 18 КБ |

Тоже самое для C - на килобайт меньше (14 КБ и 17 КБ соответственно).

Вывод - вам попалась кривая версия MinGW?

Answer (score 0):

Уменьшить можно если взять компиляторы ранних версий .Моя программа занимала 12кБ от компилятора 2020 года. Тот же компилятор 2001 года с теми же опциями сделал прогу размером 3кБ. Почему? Ответ я нашел быстро сравнив в winhex мои "одинаковые проги" от компиляторов разных лет. Та что 12 кБ содержала кучу ненужных подключенных библиотек , была захламлена пустой бесполезной информацией о версии компилятора и.т.д .